# Custom ordering of solr spellcheck collation

Tags: solr, collation, spell-checking

I know a way of ordering individual solr spellcheck suggestion by the use of `<str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>`. In this way I can order them by L-distance. But the collated results for multiple word queries always have the information on 'hits' and are ordered by them.

Just like individual suggestions, can I get the collated queries ordered by a custom comparable class? Or at least get some other information (like L-distance) in the response of the collated queries (other than 'hits')? My main goal is to select a collated query having non zero results which is least L-distant from the original query.